# Search for code or text in GitLab

Tags: search, gitlab

Is it possible to search for code or text in GitLab inside of files? I can search for files, issues, milestones, etc., but could not find a way to search for code in source files or text in the documentation i.e .doc files.

Comment: After the discussion with GItLab support, the limitation is that the search is limited to a particular repository i.e. there is no way to search across repositories.

Comment: It appears they've added this feature to Enterprise Edition, but not Community Edition. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/556

Answer (score 11):

We have a paid gitlab account such that our domain is gitlab.ourcompany.com - so this answer might not apply to all. There have been a few occassions where I needed to search for a "string" across all files in a Gitlab project, but there is no clear 'search' button. The search bar only searches for matching project names - so not what I was looking for. This method below is the easiest to use and easiest to remember.

> https://gitlab.xxxxx.com/search

[image]

Comment: Note that you still have to select a project if you want to search across files. Unfortunately, it won't search across projects.

Comment: This could not find the file containing a string. It only seemed to search by filename. If I knew the filename, I would not be here looking for how to search.

Comment: Voting down since this doesn't describe the method and the URL mentioned doesn't seem to allow what was requested (with GitLab Community 16.9.2).

Answer (score 5):

To search files on GitLab, hit URL [https://gitlab.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search_code=true&repository_ref={BranchName}](https://gitlab.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search_code=true&repository_ref=%7BBranchName%7D)

Select respective group and project from the dropdown.

Enter the text to be searched and click on 'Search' button.

Comment: this only works on paid gitlab accounts and only on repos owned by your organization

Answer (score 1):

[GitLab 16.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/07/22/gitlab-16-2-released/#command-palette) (July 2023) facilitate searches, including code search within the current project:

> ### Command palette
>
> If you’re a power user, using the keyboard to navigate and take action can be frustrating. Now, a new command palette helps you use the keyboard to get more done.
>
> To enable the command palette, open the left sidebar and click **Search GitLab** () or use the <kbd>/</kbd> key.
>
> Type one of the special characters:
>
> - <kbd>></kbd> - Create a new object or find a menu item
> - <kbd>@</kbd> - Search for a user
> - <kbd>:</kbd> - Search for a project
> - <kbd>/</kbd> - Search for project files in the default repository branch
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/command_palette.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/414974).

---

As noted by [Philippe Cloutier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5405434/philippe-cloutier) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087844/search-for-code-or-text-in-gitlab/76782645#comment137773833_76782645):

> Searching inside file contents this way only works with a *single* project (as of GitLab Community 16.9.2).
>
> Trying to search in a *group* (of projects) will just yield "`We couldn't find any projects matching [...]`".

Comment: How do you search file CONTENTS in the current project?

Comment: @Paul It should be the last option, the '`/`': then start typing what you want, and make sure "Code" is selected in the Search results section on the left side.

Comment: Searching inside file contents this way only works with a single project (as of GitLab Community 16.9.2). Trying to search in a group (of projects) will just yield "We couldn't find any projects matching [...]".

Comment: @PhilippeCloutier Good point, thank you for that feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the [python-gitlab](https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab) library to search text in the projects that you need:

```py
import gitlab


def search(gitlab_server, token, file_filter, text, group=None, project_filter=None):
    return_value = []
    gl = gitlab.Gitlab(gitlab_server, private_token=token)
    if (project_filter == '') and (group == ''):
        projects = gl.projects.list(all=True)
    else:
        group_object = gl.groups.get(group)
        group_projects = group_object.projects.list(search=project_filter)
        projects = []
        for group_project in group_projects:
            projects.append(gl.projects.get(group_project.id))
    for project in projects:
        files = []
        try:
            files = project.repository_tree(recursive=True, all=True)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e), "Error getting tree in project:", project.name)
        for file in files:
            if file_filter == file['name']:
                file_content = project.files.raw(file_path=file['path'], ref='master')
                if text in str(file_content):
                    return_value.append({
                        "project": project.name,
                        "file": file['path']
                    })
    return return_value
```

Complete example can be found here: [gitlab-search](https://github.com/tuimm/gitlab-search)

Answer (score 0):

If you have [advanced search](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/advanced_search.html) enabled, you can search the content of files using the `filename:` syntax, e.g. to search for a "string" in all files leave the filename empty:

```
string -filename:
```

That's how it could look like in the Web-UI:

[image]

Comment: Confirm that this works, though I used the pattern

"string filename:*"

Where string is what I was searching for in all files in my organization.