# Git Repositories indexing

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to know if there is a git plugin that can index the repositories?

Suppose I have many projects in Git and there is a database configuration. To find out what all projects are using this database configuration, I can clone all the projects in my local system and use grep command to find out.

Is there any plugin that can be used in Git server to index the repositories files and I can search without downloading the project?

Let me know if this is not something to be asked at SO, I will delete the question.

Comment: The answer depends on the server you're using. For instance, can't you just ssh to your server and run grep there? If not, I guess you should give more details.
(btw, in a git repo, using `git grep` is much more effective than plain old `grep`)

Comment: I can't SSH to git server and run it. Otherwise it would have been so easy. I am looking something from UI side, so that others can also use it. I am using Gitlab software.

Comment: I'm afraid gitlab doesn't seem able to answer your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087844/search-for-code-or-text-in-gitlab . If installing an ad hoc code search tool is an option, you might want to give https://github.com/etsy/hound a try