# Search in repositories (GitLab and/or Subversion ...), where google analytics / fonts are used

Tags: svn, google-analytics, gitlab, google-fonts

I've many projects maintained on GitLab (community edition 15.3.1 .. ), and also on an older SVN istance.

Now I need to know in which repos there are references to Google Analytics or Google Fonts (so, I've to search everywhere strings like "fonts.googleapis.com" and to know in which repos there area these strings ... )

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [full-text search](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/search/) feature if your SVN server is VisualSVN Server.

Here is an example:

https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#asf/search?q=googleapis.com&type=contents

As for GitLab, check the answer here: [Search for code or text in GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35087844/761095).